# touchesBegan and touchesEnded returning different touch locations after Xcode 6.3 update

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, xcode6.3, ios8.3

This is probably the most bizarre issue I've ever run into and I've got no idea where to even start looking - any help at all is greatly appreciated.

After updating to Xcode 6.3 (and the iOS 8.3 SDK) a new issue has popped up in one my old OpenGL apps where on a widescreen display, any x coordinate touches are capped at 320. This means that if I touch an x coordinate above 320, it will register as 320 in the touch.

Now the weird thing is this only happens in the touchesBegan function of my `EAGLView` - `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` can still detect up to 568, even though they have the exact same code.

Anybody know what might be causing this? Here is the touch code that's used in all 3 functions:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self] anyObject];
    CGPoint _location;
    _location = [touch locationInView:self];
    // Flip the y location ready to check it against OpenGL coordinates
    float temp = _location.x;
    _location.x = _location.y;
    _location.y = temp;
    NSLog(@"Touched at (%f,%f)", _location.x,_location.y); }
```

Comment: I've also found that if a touch is made beyond the 320 point and you keep your finger on that point, it will actually properly register it in the touches set if you tap somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out - it looks like iOS 8 causes some problems when adding a UIView directly to the window in the app delegate. I had to create a UIViewController, add the UIView to that, and then make it the root view controller.